# Is it possible to grab all the links at once on a webpage?

Tags: web-access, json-format, xml

I'm working with some webscraping using Mathematica and have run into a question: is it possible to grab all the links on a webpage that scrolls down? The page I am trying to scrape is this: "http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp?ipp=120".

I have created a scraper using XMLObjects and Cases with the following code:

```
(*Open XML Tree*)
urlShirtsPage = 
  "http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp?ipp=\
120";
getXml[anyUrl_] := (
   current = urlShirtsPage;
   page = URLFetch[urlShirtsPage];
   If[StringLength@page == 0, getXml@current, 
    Return@ImportString[page, "XMLObject"]]);
largeXml = getXml[urlShirtsPage];
(*Grab All Links*)
firstScreenLinks = Cases[largeXml,
   XMLElement[
    "div", {"class" -> "grid-item fullSize", "data-pdpurl" -> ___, 
     "data-column-index" -> __, "data-item-index" -> __}, {___}], 
   Infinity];
allLinks = secondScreenLinks = Cases[#,
     XMLElement[
       "div", {"class" -> "grid-item fullSize", 
        "data-pdpurl" -> links_, "data-column-index" -> __, 
        "data-item-index" -> __}, {___}] -> links, 1] &@
   firstScreenLinks
Length@allLinks
```

The code above basically scrapes the URLs of Nike Shirts products that are displayed in columns on the webpage. The only problem is, it only returns 120 URLs when there are 855 products (each with its own respective URLs).

Using the Chrome Developer Tools, I can see that when I scroll a certain distance the webpage pulls up another script that displays additional shirts. I locate the URL that pulls up the new script (using Developer Tools), and Import it into Mathematica using:

```
urls = "http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&\
lang_locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp&pn=2";
Import[urls, "Text"]
```

The code above indicates that the new URLs being pulled up are not in the first scraper above, which I assume means it was loaded while I was scrolling down.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to pull up all the URLs on the page (loaded and not yet loaded) rather than having to keep scrolling, checking for new scripts to appear, and importing and scraping the new URLs on Mathematica. As there are over 800 links, it would take me a very long time to perform the latter process. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Others might be able to look more closely at your code, but I do notice that if I run `Select[
 Import["http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp?ipp=120", "Hyperlinks"],
 StringContainsQ["pid-"]
 ]` I get a list of over 500 URLs

Comment: As a side note, I've written a package called [jsoupLink](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) which makes it easier to work with HTML. It is an alternative to the symbolic XML pattern matching approach.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the URL that you found, you'll notice a parameter `pn`. If you change this parameter you get another set of t-shirts. To get all t-shirts you need to download that URL for all allowed `pn`. Let's say `pn` stands for "page number". Now, how many pages are there?

We have to remember that this is part of an API. Another programmer used the response of this very URL to implement the website. He must have known how to download all t-shirts, so how did he do it? We must investigate.

We download `pn=1` and convert the list of rules to an `Association` object, which is easier to deal with:

```
startURL = "http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&lang_locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp&pn=1";
res = GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations[Import[startURL, "JSON"]];
```

We look at the keys of the `Association` to see what kind of data we have downloaded:

```
Keys[res]

(* Out: {"heading", "analytics", "trackingData", "seoBlurb", \
"productsEnabled", "cqIncludes", "nextPageDataService", \
"foundResults", "foundProductResults", "sections", "banners", \
"documentTitle", "navigation", "searchReport"} *)
```

`nextPageDataService` sounds interesting, let's have a look:

```
res["nextPageDataService"]

(* Out: "http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&lang_\
locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-tops-t-shirts/7puZobp&pn=2" *)
```

It turns out that `nextPageDataService` gives us the next page's URL.

What we now have to do is download `nextPageDataService` recursively until the response lacks the `nextPageDataService` key, which means that we're at the last page. It can be implemented like this:

```
getPage[url_] := GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations[Import[url, "JSON"]];

data = NestWhileList[
   getPage[#["nextPageDataService"]] &,
   getPage[startURL],
   KeyExistsQ[#, "nextPageDataService"] &
   ];
```

`data` now contains all the information available about all t-shirts.

I started by asking what the possible values of `pn` are. It turns out that we didn't need to know, because the API was recursive by nature. But we can now find it out anyway:

```
data // Length
(* Out: 15 *)
```

Which means that `pn` ranges from 1 to 15.

Comment: You have forgotten to add the definition of `getPage`.

Comment: @Edmund Thank you for pointing this out. In case you are trying to run this, you should be aware that the URL does not seem to be working anymore. They probably update it regularly to make it harder to scrape data.

Comment: I think `<|Import[startURL, "JSON"]|>` also can work

Comment: @yode No, try f.e. `<|{"test" -> {"test1" -> 1}}|>`. It doesn't transform inner lists.